# Elasticsearch : How to dynamically pass range query variables in Elasticsearch query

Tags: elasticsearch

How can we pass dynamic values for timestamp into the filter range query from script which contains values for dynamicValueLte and dynamicValueGte.
Like below example. (Elasticsearch version 7.1.1)

Elasticsearch Code below

```
"filter": [
{
"range": {
"@timestamp": {
"lte": "now-{{dynamicValueLte}}",
"gte": "now-{{dynamicValueGte}}"
}
}
}
}
]
```

Comment: How are you making the request? Kibana, Node.js, anything else?

Comment: @Milen - through Visual studio Code- created python file which will call Elasticsearch/Kibana cluster and retrieve data from the index. Can you please provide some details how to pass variables dynamically. Appreciate your help!!

Answer (score 0):

Use search_templates. When making a subsequent request, pass parameters into the template.

[Elasticsearch Search Template Documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-template.html)

In your case, this would simply be the same search request, with variables for whatever you have in the curly braces.